# Как вызвать хранимую процедуру MSSQL в PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, хранимые-процедуры

Пробую вызвать результат хранимой процедуры вот так:

```
<?php
    include "sql.php";
    $params = "'1922'"; //строковый параметр 
    $sql = "{call dc_GetLast (@CODE = ?)}";    
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql,$params);
    
    var_dump($stmt); // тут пусто
        
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

Подскажите ,с чем может быть связано?

Comment: Во-первых - нет такого понятия "пусто", метод `sqlsrv_query` не возвращает __пусто__. Во-вторых - есть обработка ошибок. В-третьих -  `$params` должен быть массивом.

Comment: *Подскажите ,с чем может быть связано?* Связано - что? то, что Вы "пробуете вызвать результат хранимой процедуры вот так"? Ну что за бред-то, право слово... надо же смотреть, что пишешь.

Comment: Я понял , что вызываю её не верно, Подскажите, тогда как правильно вызывать хранимую процедуру mssql  ?

Answer (score 1):

Заработало. Если кто столкнётся, то указывайте путь до хранимки полный `DB.dbo.dc_functionName`.

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек, дай бог здоровья!